# how do I switch between the pygame screen and the visual studies code screen?

Tags: python, pygame, visual-studio-debugging

I'm new to python so hopefully this is an easy one. When I use these instructions in my code:

```
surface = pygame.display.set_mode((max_width, max_height))
surface.fill(white) 
pygame.display.update()
```

I get a pop up screen that shows graphics that I want to draw. All well and good, but is there an easy way to swap back and forth between the code and the output display while a program is running for debugging as the popup covers the code screen?

Comment: This hasn't anything to do with either pygame or visual studio code, but rather how you switch between applications on your OS. How you do it is dependent on what OS you're using. On Mac it's cmd + tab, on Windows it's alt + tab (I think)

Comment: You can minimalize vscode and place it besides your game screen but it would do it like the awnser above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This hasn't anything to do with either pygame or visual studio code, but rather how you switch between applications on your OS. How you do it is dependent on what OS you're using. On Mac it's cmd + tab, on Windows it's alt + tab